# Inflar Toolbar em Stepper

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragment

Preciso criar um Stepper na minha aplicação que consegui a biblioteca no GitHub https://github.com/shivasurya/materialsteppers

Consegui implementar a aplicação, porem quero colocar uma Toolbar para inflar um menu e ter o botão de voltar nela, porem nao estou conseguindo colocar na aplicação. Segue os códigos:

Xml tela 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarSessao2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        style="@style/FundoAPP"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarSessao2"
        android:layout_gravity="right">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                style="@style/titleHints"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hint_sessao_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
                android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
                android:paddingTop="24dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/JN_04_01"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:hint="@string/hintHora"
                    android:textColorHint="#ffa3a3a3" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <View style="@style/Divider" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                style="@style/Textos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
                android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
                android:paddingTop="24dp"
                android:text="@string/Repet" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

A tela 2 é parecida com essa acima...

Esse é o fragment dessa tela acima:

```
public class sessao_fragment1 extends stepperFragment implements View.OnClickListener{


    public sessao_fragment1(){

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.sessao1, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_jn_04_sessao, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNextButtonHandler() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

O da segunda tela também é igual...

E essa é a tela que controla o Stepper:

```js
public class stepper_sessao extends progressMobileStepper implements View.OnClickListener{


        List<Class> stepperFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public List<Class> init() {
            stepperFragmentList.add(sessao_fragment1.class);
            stepperFragmentList.add(sessao_fragment2.class);

            return stepperFragmentList;
        }

 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarSessao2);
            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.title_activity_inserir_programacao);
            toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTextButton));
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            // Set an OnMenuItemClickListener to handle menu item clicks
            toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    // Handle the menu item
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.manutencao_sessoes:
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), jn_14_manutencao_sessao.class));
                            break;

                        case R.id.cad_Remedio:
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), jn_03_remedio.class));
                            break;

                        case R.id.salvarSessao:
                            //SALVAR();
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_jn_04_sessao);
            
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            
            return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStepperCompleted() {
            showCompletedDialog();
        }


        protected void showCompletedDialog(){
            android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(
                    stepper_sessao.this);

            // set title
            /*alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Hooray");
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("We've completed the stepper")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        }
                    });
            */
            // create alert dialog
            android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
            //finish();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
        }


    }
```

A toolbar que eu coloquei esta comentada nessa ultima tela, mas não foi correta... se puderem ajudar!

esse é o erro:

```
02-14 23:05:48.443 1354-1354/com.housepharm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.housepharm, PID: 1354
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.housepharm/com.housepharm.Visao.Tela.stepper_sessao}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi dessa biblioteca, a forma mais simple é ter uma Activity que configure e controle o `Stepper`, não sei se é isso que está acontecendo. Mas o toolbar deveria ser configurado na `Activity` e não no Fragment. Só que me parece que o `stepper_sessao` é um `Fragment`. Você está usando um Fragment para controlar o `Stepper`?

Comment: Então, olhei o código dele, a unica coisa que faz na MainActivity é extender a progressMobileStepper, porem, o projeto dele tem como style DarkActionBar e eu estou usando Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar; Tentei tambem, depois que você falou, colocar o Toolbar dentro do onCreate ao invés do onCreateView, porem deu erro java.lang.NullPointerException depois de criar o objeto

Comment: Aonde gera o erro? Poderia alterar a pergunta com o código que gerou o erro?

Comment: completei la o código conforme pediu